# как получить имя файла из URI без пути

Tags: android, uri

```
Uri music = intent.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);

String nameFile = music.toString();
```

Так получается имя и полный путь file:///storage ... имя_файла.mp3
А как получить только имя, без пути и желательно без расширения?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например:

```
String fileName=new File(uri.getPath()).getName(); //даст имя с расширением
//извлекаем имя без расширения
int pos = fileName.lastIndexOf(".");
if (pos > 0) 
   name = name.substring(0, pos);
else
   name = fileName;
```